# How to add sum in my input value and chage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
<input id=​"InvoiceItemPrice:​:​:​:​" name=​"InvoiceItemPrice:​:​:​:​" value size=​"6">​
<input id=​"InvoiceItemPrice:​:​1:​:​" name=​"InvoiceItemPrice:​:​1:​:​" value=​"46.00" size=​"6">​
<input id=​"InvoiceItemPrice:​:​2:​:​" name=​"InvoiceItemPrice:​:​2:​:​" value=​"79.00" size=​"6">​, 
<input id=​"InvoiceItemPrice:​:​3:​:​" name=​"InvoiceItemPrice:​:​3:​:​" value=​"14.00" size=​"6">​
```

I like add sum in every value ot input type i have this code:

```
var sum = 100/123;
$('input[name="InvoiceItemPrice::2::"]').each(function()
{
    sum *= parseFloat($(this).val());
});
$('input[name="InvoiceItemPrice::2::"]').val(sum);
```

How to change all value on all input.

I tried with this `$("input [name = ' * InvoiceItemPrice ']")` but I caught the first that does not have a value and `NaN` gives me an error.

Comment: Instead of selecting on name, why don't you add a class and select via that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is your sum variable is getting re-used in your each statement, if you change that line inside of your each you should be A-ok.

I have created a jsFiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/r79d3121/3/ which may help

HTML

```
<input id="InvoiceItemPrice::::" name="InvoiceItemPrice::::" value size="6">
<input id="InvoiceItemPrice::1::" name="InvoiceItemPrice::1::" value="46.00" size="6">
<input id="InvoiceItemPrice::2::" name="InvoiceItemPrice::2::" value="79.00" size="6">,
<input id="InvoiceItemPrice::3::" name="InvoiceItemPrice::3::" value="14.00" size="6">
```

jQuery

```
var sum = parseFloat(100 / 123);
$(function () {
    var result = 0;
    $('[id*="InvoiceItemPrice"]').each(function () {
        $(this).val(parseFloat((parseFloat($(this).val()) * parseFloat(sum))));
    });
});
```

Updated to change only the value from the input selected

2nd Update, values are calculated when the document is ready, if you want the values to be updated you could always check for `.focusout()` on each input and then run the code to calculate the value

3rd Update, the html is back to the original and also, you can just user a partial selector in your jQuery which I have provided and updated the jsFiddle link

Comment: Hi tnx but i like It considers only the last value and I want any number of value to be considered 100/123. For example, the first expression is 46x100/134 then 79x100/123 and then 14x100/123.

Comment: @HealthlikeLive  I have updated my jsFiddle and jQuery, have a look now

Comment: Oh no now I saw coming to me generated by php: InvoiceItemPrice: 1:: InvoiceItemPrice: and: 2: and when your script is different it is with one name and ID?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$('input[name^=InvoiceItemPrice]').each(function() {
$(this).val("example");
});
```